# Layout Folder For Tablet Not Recognized

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a simple application with  two .xml files. One for the Nexus 5 phone, placed in the res/layout folder, and the other for the Nexus 10 tablet. Both of these are run on the Genymotion emulator. I created multiple folders in my res folder for the tablet layout, including "layout-large", "layoutsw600dp","layout-xlarge-xhdpi", but non are being recognized when the application is launched.

My tablet .xml file contains a widget that I called fragmentContainer. My Java code looks for this file, if it is not there in the "chosen" .xml then the .xml for the phone is used:

```
public void itemClicked(long id) {
    View fragmentContainer  = findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
    if(fragmentContainer!=null){
        WorkoutDetailFragment details = new WorkoutDetailFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        details.setWorkoutID(id);

        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, details);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.commit();
    }else{
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_WORKOUT_ID,id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

I've tried a bunch of different folders but non of them are being recognized for the tablet. Anyone know why? Should there be specific settings in my Manifest File? Here is the full file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mark.fragments" >

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: could you please post your entire manifest file?

Comment: Try checking it on a real device if you can. Emulators aren't always right.

Comment: as far as the manifest, you don't have to add anything extra in order to enable res "auto" lookup and your manifest looks ok. The problem is most likely related emulators.